# "Auto Layout before OS X 10.7"

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have an app in the app store, FractalWorks, which is based on a very old code-base. It's a big app, with quite a few screens. It was created in Objective-C before auto-synthesized properties were a thing, to give you an idea of how long ago it was created.

I wrote the app when I had a full-time gig as an independent software developer. I've since taken a day job, and support my apps in my spare time.

It still sells fairly well, and I recently used to add a section to the Wikipedia article on the Mandelbrot set on 3D images: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#3D_images_of_Mandelbrot_and_Julia_sets

I'm fluent in Auto-Layout now, but haven't taken the time to update the app's XIB files from "struts and springs" style to Auto-Layout - nor do I want to invest the time to do so if I can possibly help it.

I want to add a minor enhancement to the app that involves adding some UI elements and making one of the windows slightly taller. The minute I try to use Interface Builder to edit my XIB, it apparently silently changes it to Auto-Layout, and then complains about "Auto Layout before OS X 10.7". (It was released to the app store for OS X version 10.4, if memory serves, and I've moved the OS version up to the lowest version I could get away with in order to support legacy customers. It currently supports ≥10.6. The original, pre app-store version used even older OS versions.)

Googling this error suggests I use the file inspector on my XIB file to un-check a "Use AutoLayout" checkbox, but I don't see any such checkbox.

What am I missing?

If I use Xcode's code review button to compare the XIB file before and after editing it, various "tool version" values are changed, as well as it gaining a setting `useAutolayout="YES"`. Editing that to read `useAutolayout="NO"` does not solve the problem.

Comment: There is no requirement to use autolayout in a nib file in any version of Xcode. There is always a way to say no thanks. What Xcode version did you say this was?

Comment: I didn't say, and probably should have. I'm using Xcode 11.3.1. This is the first time I've ever seen this problem. From the `useAutolayout="YES"` entry in the XIB file it's pretty clear that it **is** in fact setting Autolayout on my XIB without my asking for it to do so.

Comment: OK, so Xcode 11 has a whole new way of doing this. In IB, select the View. First I would suggest you go into the File menu and change Interface Builder Document Open In to something more modern. Then switch to the Size inspector and set the Layout popup menu to Translates Mask; that will tell it that you want to use autoresizing. Be careful not to make any constraints, as that will cause an incoherent situation.

Comment: Alternatively you could just do this in Xcode 10.x where the checkbox to turn off autolayout for the whole nib still exists.

Comment: Hmm on the other hand maybe the best solution is just drop support for everything before 10.7. Backward compatibility is really hard even at the best of times.

Comment: @matt why don't you post this as an answer? It worked for me.

Comment: @DimitarNestorov Well it evidently hasn't worked for the OP.

Comment: @matt it may have worked but OP forgot to confirm. I still suggest to post as an answer since this question is the first result on Google.

Comment: @DimitarNestorov You post an answer if you like! I yield to you.

Comment: @matt Thanks! 

Comment: The way I solved it was to open the XIB as a source code file and change useAutolayout to NO and then search and replace all instances of translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" totranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="YES"

Answer (score 6):

All the credit goes to [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) and his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270760/auto-layout-before-os-x-10-7?noredirect=1#comment106613600_60270760).

**1. In the Navigator (left panel) go to issue navigator and click on the error.**

[image]

**2. In the Inspectors panel (right panel) the Size inspector will be automatically selected. Switch Layout from Automatic to Translates Mask Into Constraints.**

[image]

Update: It's called Autoresizing Mask now.

[image: Autoresizing Mask option]

**3. Repeat for every occurrence of this error.**

---

You may end up with an error not in the Illegal Configuration group like the following which opens the All Messages view in the middle and doesn't open the Size inspector.

[image]

This is a compile time error, just build/run your app again.

---

And also from the previously mentioned comment:

> Be careful not to make any constraints, as that will cause an incoherent situation.

Answer (score -2):

If you have multiple auto layout errors, which in all likelihood you will have,  select all the controls in a window and perform the operation once rather than for each individual control. Repeat for each window.